# Display dynamic contents with using bootstrap pagination?

Tags: php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, pagination

How can I display the dynamic content of PHP with bootstrap pagination.The result is displaying using ajax call in div id 'msrResult', how to relate with bootstrap pagination code.
 Here my code:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//raw.github.com/botmonster/jquery-bootpag/master /lib/jquery.bootpag.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>

<div id="content2">Dynamic Content goes here</div>
<div id="page-selection">Pagination goes here</div>
<script>
   $('#page-selection').bootpag({
    total: 23,
    page: 1,
    maxVisible: 10
    }).on('page', function(event, num){
    $("#content2").html("Page " + num); // or some ajax content loading...
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>

<div id=msrResult></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you already use jQuery, there is a nice shorthand method called 'load'.

See: http://api.jquery.com/load/

Because your content-pane hast the id content2, you can use it as follows within the page-change-event:

```
$('#content2').load('http://your.url.com/path/thecontent.php');
```

You don't need to handle events for async ajax etc. This shorthand method does the trick. All you have to do is to specify *which* content you want to load. You can do this directly by the url or by additional GET-parameters.

For example when you want to use the GET-parameter page with the corresponding number:

```
.on('page', function(event, num){
  $('#content2').load('http://your.url.com/path/thecontent.php', { page: num });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This will retrieve the content you want from the url specified into the container #msrResult.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    // init bootpag
    $('#page-selection').bootpag({
    total: 23,
    page: 1,
    maxVisible: 10
   }).on('page', function(event, num){
      $.ajax({
       url: "pageofresults?pageNumber="+num,
      }).done(function(data) {
       $("#msrResult").html( data );
      });

    });
  });
```